# Standard for typesetting texts in subscripts

Tags: subscripts

what is the correct way of typesetting words in indices for example
`\varphi_{el}`
looks weird because it is in italics. Is this right?
`\varphi_\text{el}`
same for
`\oint_{Volume}` and `\oint_\text{Volume}`.

And since I think the `_\text{}` version looks better does this affect normal indices as well; so `\sum_i F_i` of `\sum_\text{i} F_\text{i}`

Is there a standard, because I have seen both out in the wild. Or is there an easier way of typesetting this?

[image]

Comment: It's not because words are typeset in italic, but because their inter-letter spacing is larger than the normal spacing inside words.  And no, an index is a variable, and should be typed in math italic (at least for lowercase, since this depends on the convention for each language: in French, capital letters are – should be– typeset in roman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rules  are:

1. Math objects should be typeset in math mode.
2. As the font carry meaning in math, it is important that a variable
   is always typeset in the same way. It should not be in one equation
   in bold and in the next in italic.

This means that `\text` is normally not the correct command for multiletter variables. As the name indicates it switches to text mode; also it follows the surrounding font. Use it only as a workaround if your variable names contains chars like umlauts or accented chars that doesn't work with `\mathXX`.

In all other cases use the `\mathXX` commands, which one depends on the conventions of your field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\varphi_{\mathrm{el}} = 1 \text{ and } \varphi_{\text{\normalfont äl}} = 2 $  

$\varphi_{\mathit{el}} = 1 \text{ and } \varphi_{\text{\normalfont\itshape äl}} = 2 $  


\bfseries 
$\varphi_{\mathrm{el}} = 1 \text{ and } \varphi_{\text{\normalfont äl}} = 2 $

$\varphi_{\mathit{el}} = 1 \text{ and } \varphi_{\text{\normalfont\itshape äl}} = 2 $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a list of those conventions somewhere?

Comment: Just as a help to future people: in Germany everything inside an equation has to be in italics (DIN 1338). So I am using `_\mathit` from hereon. thanks!